# Matching conditions in columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, conditional-statements

I am trying to match conditions so that if text is present in both columns A and B and a 0 is in column C, the code should return 'new' in column C (overwriting the 0). Example dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":['something',None,'filled',None], "B":['test','test','test',None], "C":['rt','0','0','0']})
```

I have tried the following, however it only seems to accept the last condition so that any '0' entries in column C become 'new' regardless of None in columns A or B. (in this example I only expect 'new' to appear on row 2.

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [(df['A'] is not None) & (df['B'] is not None) & (df['C'] == '0')]

values = ['new']

df['C'] = np.select(conditions, values, default=df["C"])
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `.isna()` and filter where it is not nan/none (using `~`) as below:

```
conditions = [~(df['A'].isna()) & ~(df['B'].isna()) & (df['C'] == '0')]
```

output:

```
           A     B    C
0  something  test   rt
1       None  test    0
2     filled  test  new
3       None  None    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) for test `None` or `NaN`s:

```
conditions = [df['A'].notna() & df['B'].notna() & (df['C'] == '0')]
```

Or:

```
conditions = [df[['A','B']].notna().all(axis=1) & (df['C'] == '0')]
```

---

```
values = ['new']

df['C'] = np.select(conditions, values, default=df["C"])
print (df)
           A     B    C
0  something  test   rt
1       None  test    0
2     filled  test  new
3       None  None    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mask = df[['A', 'B']].notna().all(1) & df['C'].eq('0')
df.loc[mask, 'C'] = 'new'
```